# Find specific text in a DIV according to offset in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, css-position

I want to insert an image tag into a block of text so that the image is, say, 100 pixels down in the DIV.

```
    <div>
    A lot of text in a text block and a <img tag> somewhere
that is floated left or right and positioned inside the text block
    </div>
```

So, the  tag above is put in the text block to be floated so that it is positioned at 100px DOWN in the DIV. Now, this can't be done statically, it has to be done in javascript since 100px down in the div may be represented by different text depending on font rendering issues and such.

So, is there a way to find what "word" in a text block that is 100px down in the DIV? jQuery perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

**The short answer is [no](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20020422/110518.html)**

Basically it comes down to the DOM doesn't give a way for you to get an elements pixel position. There are sort of hacks you can do for some browsers, but good luck getting a solution working.

If you cannot get the position of the containing div, you are not going to get the position for the text within.

**Leaving aside the [no](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20020422/110518.html)**, if you were to find a way to get the div's pixel height, I would follow a procedure similar to the following.

1. Get the text from inside the div and store it in a local var.

   2. Inside a loop for each word in the text:
   3. Insert a div tag into just before the word.
   4. Get the pixel position of the div tag.
   5. Use this to determine the closest word to pixel pos 100 down.
2. Once you have the closest position, create a document fragment to build up your new inner for the div
3. Replace the div's content with the document fragment.

Comment: Sorry, I just ruined that :( haha

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution. I have to test it to see how it works speed-wise, sounds like it could be pretty cpu consuming

Comment: Thanks. Each loop will cause a reflow. If you have a lot of words, that is a lot of work.

Comment: Just a thought. Using the concept of binary search, you can greatly reduce the amount of reflows and position checks you need to do.

Comment: I get it now. I rather think that I should compute the line-height, font-size and then the width of the container to find the *probable* position of the insertion, and positioning it there, and then move it one word back/forward until it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party and sorry for the possible off-topic. In my case, texts are stored as `<p>`s in a `<div>` and I have to find the element (thus text too) in the vertical center of the `div` (for 'splitting' the `div` into 2-column layout dynamically according to its contents length). So I made this one:

```
function getElAtTheVerticalCenterOf(el) {
  //get el's rect and positions
  const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
        elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        scroll = elRect.y - bodyRect.y,
        marginLeft = elRect.x;

  //store current window scroll
  const orgX = window.scrollX, orgY = window.scrollY;

  //scroll to the vertical center of el to find the target
  const elHeight = el.clientHeight;
  window.scrollTo(0, scroll + elHeight/2);
  const target = document.elementFromPoint(marginLeft, 0);

  //scroll back to original window scroll
  window.scrollTo(orgX, orgY);

  return target;
}
```

Main idea is:

1. get how much to scroll.
2. scroll `window` to wanted position (in order to use `elementFromPoint()` there).
3. get the target element
4. scroll back to the original position.

As for `getBoundingClientRect()` or `elementFromPoint()`, please look for the corresponding articles. Note that `offsetTop` is `int` and was not enough accurate for this function to work. I can't believe it, but I had to stick to `getBoundingClientRect()` (`float`) instead of `offsetTop`.